# Servlet for receive and share streaming data

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets

I have three programs (`a`-`b`-`c`): `a` starts `b` that handles `c`, when `c` ends `a` restarts `b`. I can only change `b`, but it is unstable because it is restarted. I was thinking of solving my problems with a servlet service that receives `b` data and errors and displays them on a web page immediately.  I tried two ways:  1. Receive data in a `Thread` parallel to the servlet and share it with it (I did not succeed);  2. Receive data from a client and share it with ServletContext and refresh the page with sent event but skip lines, even with retry: 100, and repeat the last one when there are no new data.  Is there a way to send data to all servlet clients only when they are new? Is there a better solution considering that `b` is restarted and that I have to limit the ports used?

--UPDATE--
Servlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;

@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/Servlet", "/test"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        String datain = request.getParameter("StringIn");
        String dataold = request.getParameter("StringOld");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        if (datain == null) {
            boolean test = getServletContext().getAttribute("actualData").equals(request.getParameter("StringOld"));
            if (!test) {
                writer.write("data: " + getServletContext().getAttribute("actualData") +"\n\n");
                writer.write("retry: 500");
            }
            else {
                writer.write("data: \n\n");
                writer.write("retry: 1000");
            }
        }
        else {
            getServletContext().setAttribute("actualData", datain);
            writer.write("data receive!\n\n");
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Script index.jsp

```
var eventSource = null;
var oldmessage = "";
var path = "http://localhost:8080/Servlet?StringaOld=";
function start() {
    eventSource = new EventSource(path + oldmessage);
    eventSource.onopen = function () {
    };
    eventSource.onmessage = function (message) {
        var mex = message.data;
        message.data = null;
        if (mex != null) {
            oldmex = mex;
            testo.value += mex + "\n";
        }
    };
    eventSource.onerror = function (error) {
        eventSource = new EventSource(path + encodeURI(oldmessage));
    };
    Start.disabled = true;
}

function stop() {
    eventSource.close();
    Start.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: extremly broad, a poor written question

Comment: @JacekCz can I send the state event only when updating the value? Do I need a buffer or is it instantaneous? I added an example of code!

Comment: sevlet, safe background thread is one pool of knowledge (hard to teach in short words). The second: I have never write streaming, value of my comment will be no more than google

Comment: The third: hard to understand together Your description and code. IMHO have not too much